# Sorting direction: Views.GetView method

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I use SharePoint Server through web-services. 
To get View schema I use [GetView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.views.getview%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method of Views.asmx. But it returns only FieldRefs with Names, without isAscending. 
 How would I know if View's field has sort direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetView returns Ascending property:
1) for SP Server 2010: only if it set to FALSE;
2) for Office365: always.

Answer (score 2):

You can find that actually in the 2nd part of the returned Xml, but only when using the GetViewHtml method, because that is part of the Query (search for the OrderBy), see here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.views.getviewhtml(v=office.12).aspx. You could use Linq to Xml by example to retrieve the QUERY element.

Comment: By experimenting with GetView I've found out that GetView returns Ascending property but: only if it's FALSE (for SP Server 2010) and always for Office365 (SP Server Online). Thanks a lot for pointing out to GetViewHtml method!